# .class + .class doesn't work

Tags: css, class

I'm trying to figure out how to use the .class + .class feature in CSS and I cannot figure out how to make it work. I'm trying to to get it to when to .regLink classes are next to each other it adds a margin of 50px between them. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rtohocqL/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="regLink">Register</a> 
<a href="#" class="regLink">Login</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.regLink + .regLink {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It works as mentioned, it will apply right margin to the next adjacent sibling element.

Comment: @Mr_Green for some reason, I was under the impression it'd do the first class with the margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because  `.regLink + .regLink` only selecting the **second** `a` tag,

so change `margin-right` to `margin-left`

```
   .regLink + .regLink {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rtohocqL/2/

about the **CSS +**  you can read this post [http://www.w3.org/....](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: Oh, wow... Really? Why does it have to be left? Not that'll break anything, but that seems kind of silly.

Comment: @ErraticFox Because you're selecting the second one, so you need the left margin to be big, so that it gets pushed over.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware which one it selected. I guess that does make sense when I seen that margin highlighted in inspect element... Sleep deprivation is getting to me. Thanks though, will accept answer when it lets me!

Answer (score 1):

[This link can help you understand **css selectors** more specifically.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors)

As your issue, there is two ways to achieve it at least. The reason is why B + E doesn't work is that **B + E   Any Eelement that is the next sibling of a B element (that is: the next child of the same parent.)**

```
 1. .regLink{
        margin-right:50px;
    }
 2. a:first-of-type{
        margin-right:50px;
    }
```

```css
a:first-of-type{margin-right:50px;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="regLink">Register</a> 
<a href="#" class="regLink">Login</a>
```